# why Java repaint() method not working?

Tags: java, swing, paint, repaint

The code below is a very simple test which involves an image.
It should repaint an image whenever I send "a" to System.in and it should exit the program whenever I send "q".

The problem is that only the exit works:
the method paint() is never called, and I don't why.

I checked for the call to "super.paint()", tried replacing paint(Graphics g) with paintCompoenent(Graphics g) but nothing seems to work: simply there's no call.

Is the problem involving the Scanner in main()?

The path in the program is not the same I used, and the first paint is right, so the problem shouldn't be there.

NB if it's useful, I'm using Eclipse Oxygen and Java9 SE

Thanks to all!

code paste:

```
public class TestImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;
    private String _imagePath = "//myFolder//image.png";

    public TestImagePanel() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(_imagePath));
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        System.out.println("painting LOG");
        g.drawImage(image, this.xpos++, this.ypos++, this);
    }

    public void update(String a) {
        System.out.print("Receiving:" + a + "---" + xpos + ":" + ypos);
        if (a.equals("a"))
            repaint();
        else if (a.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("LOGOUT");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        TestImagePanel testimg = new TestImagePanel();
        frame.add(new TestImagePanel());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true)
            testimg.update( in .next());
    }
}
```

Comment: I just tested your code and had no issues. What are you expecting to have happen that isn't happening? It isn't clear from your question. The `repaint()` method is called, it just doesn't do anything because there is nothing to do.

Comment: You're also calling `new TestImagePanel()` twice - once where you assign it to `testimg`, and you add a different one to the `frame`

Comment: I expect the image to be repainted at a new xpos and ypos, they should get a ++

Comment: Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246308/how-to-combine-the-gui-class-and-the-scanner-class) -- you're `tying up your GUI's event thread for console input` - don't use Scanner for input for your GUI app. Key info you should focus on is the concept of swing's "event dispatch thread" - a good read is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484425/how-does-the-event-dispatch-thread-work)

Comment: *"I expect the image to be repainted at a new xpos and ypos, they should get a ++ "* - You're updating an instance of `testimg` which is not on the screen

Answer (score 4):

So, there's a few mistakes...

Let's start here...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
TestImagePanel testimg = new TestImagePanel();
frame.add(new TestImagePanel());

//...

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true)
    testimg.update( in .next());
```

You're creating two instances of `TestImagePanel` and you're only updating the instance which is not on the screen

Something like...

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
TestImagePanel testimg = new TestImagePanel();
frame.add(testimg);

//...

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true)
    testimg.update( in .next());
```

will help.

Next...

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    System.out.println("painting LOG");
    g.drawImage(image, this.xpos++, this.ypos++, this);
}
```

Okay, you should avoid overriding `paint`, as a general preference it's recommend to override `paintComponent` instead.

Because painting can occur at any time for any number of reasons, you should never update or modify the state of the UI from within paint methods, painting is for painting the current state

So, it should be something more like...

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawImage(image, this.xpos, this.ypos, this);
}
```

Okay, so, then how do we update the `xpos` and `ypos` values?  In your case, the `update` method is probably the obvious choice....

```
public void update(String a) {
    xpos++;
    ypos++;
    System.out.print("Receiving:" + a + "---" + xpos + ":" + ypos);
    if (a.equals("a"))
        repaint();
    else if (a.equals("q")) {
        System.out.println("LOGOUT");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Now, this raises an issue.  `xpos` and `ypos` are needed by the `paintComponent` method, this means that these values should not be updated outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread

A simple fix might be to do something like...

```
public void update(String a) {
    if (!EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                update(a);
            }
        });
    }
    xpos++;
    ypos++;
    System.out.print("Receiving:" + a + "---" + xpos + ":" + ypos);
    if (a.equals("a")) {
        repaint();
    } else if (a.equals("q")) {
        System.out.println("LOGOUT");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

This ensures that the contents of the `update` method is executed within the context of the EDT.

This, IMHO, is kind of a mess.  A better solution would be to use a `SwingWorker`

```
SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            publish(in.next());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        for (String text : chunks) {
            testimg.update(text);
        }
    }

};
```

This takes care of putting the updates onto the EDT for us.

This generates a solution which looks something like this...

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class TestImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private int xpos = 0;
    private int ypos = 0;
    private String _imagePath = "//myFolder//image.png";

    public TestImagePanel() {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(_imagePath));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.println("painting LOG");
        g.drawImage(image, this.xpos, this.ypos, this);
    }

    public void update(String a) {
        System.out.print("Receiving:" + a + "---" + xpos + ":" + ypos);
        if (a.equals("a")) {
            xpos++;
            ypos++;
            repaint();
        } else if (a.equals("q")) {
            System.out.println("LOGOUT");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        TestImagePanel testimg = new TestImagePanel();
        frame.add(new TestImagePanel());
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                while (true) {
                    publish(in.next());
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                for (String text : chunks) {
                    testimg.update(text);
                }
            }

        };

    }
}
```

Now, the question is, why are you taking input from the console in a GUI program?  You should be inputing data via the GUI?  The above might be a good solution for reading content from a file or other automated source, but should be avoid for user input ... this isn't how GUIs are suppose to work.

Comment: `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);` should be `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);` in two places. Barring that, great answer.

Comment: ‍♂️copy and paste

Comment: Thank you very much for your completeness, this is really helpful

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not override the paint() method; you shoul;d override paintComponent() instead.

Second, you are not doing this on the EventDispatchThread. And even if you were, putting the updates in a loop will block the event dispatch thread until the loop ends, resulting in only one final repaint.

Comment: `repaint` is thread safe - but you are probably right on the fact that they are probably spamming the EDT