# How do I make my two classes function together?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am working on a text-based videogame and created a GUI for it, however, I am having issues getting my two classes to work together. I have a text field in my GUI class that receives input from the user, which I want to send to my Player class so that it can compare it and execute the appropriate methods. I am still very new to programming, so I hope that some of you out there might be able to help me. Excuse the horrendous code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class GUI extends Player {
    String input;
    JLabel message;
    public GUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SPACE GAME");

        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("rocket.png");

        frame.setIconImage(image.getImage());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1200, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.getContentPane();


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JTextField commandLine = new JTextField(30);
        JLabel message = new JLabel();

        frame.add(panel);

        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1000, 1000 ,1000 ,1000));

        commandLine.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        commandLine.setBounds(5, 730, 300, 30);
        commandLine.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 3));
        commandLine.setFont(new Font("Zig", Font.PLAIN, 18));
        commandLine.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        commandLine.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        commandLine.setCaretColor(Color.GREEN);
        commandLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                String input = commandLine.getText();
            }
        });
        commandLine.setVisible(false);


        message.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        message.setText("Welcome to SPACE GAME! Press any key to start.");
        message.setBounds(5,665, 1000, 100);
        message.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 18));


        panel.add(message);
        panel.add(commandLine);


        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                commandLine.setVisible(true);
                commandLine.requestFocusInWindow();
                message.setText("Type \"help\" for help");
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

            }
        });
    }
    public JLabel getMessage(JLabel message) {
        return message;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {
    //Attributes
    private Room currentRoom;
    Player player;
    JLabel message;
 // Handles player movement and commands
 public void move() {
     player = new Player();
     Map map = new Map();
     GUI gui = new GUI();
     player.currentRoom = map.room1;
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("You are in " + player.currentRoom.getName() + ". " + player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
     System.out.println("Type \"help\" to get help");

     //Commands
     boolean isGameRunning = true;
     while (isGameRunning) {
         String goMessage = input.nextLine();
         goMessage = goMessage.toLowerCase();
         switch (goMessage) {
             case "go north", "north", "go n", "n": goNorth(); break;
             case "go east", "east", "go e", "e": goEast(); break;
             case "go south", "south", "go s", "s": goSouth(); break;
             case "go west", "west", "go w", "w": goWest(); break;
             case "exit": isGameRunning = false; break;
             case "look":
                 System.out.println(player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
                 break;
             case "help":
                 System.out.println("""
                            "go (north, south, east, west)" to choose a direction to go.
                            "look" gives you a description of the room.
                            "exit" stops the game.""");
                 break;
             default:
                 System.out.println("Unknown command");
                 break;
         }
     }
 }
    public void goNorth() {
        if (player.currentRoom.getNorthRoom() != null) {
            player.currentRoom = player.currentRoom.getNorthRoom();
            System.out.println("You are in " + player.currentRoom.getName() + ". " + player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot go that way");
        }
    }
    public void goEast() {
        if (player.currentRoom.getEastRoom() != null) {
            player.currentRoom = player.currentRoom.getEastRoom();
            System.out.println("You are in " + player.currentRoom.getName() + ". " + player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot go that way");
        }
    }
    public void goSouth() {
        if (player.currentRoom.getSouthRoom() != null) {
            player.currentRoom = player.currentRoom.getSouthRoom();
            System.out.println("You are in " + player.currentRoom.getName() + ". " + player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot go that way");
        }
    }
    public void goWest() {
        if (player.currentRoom.getWestRoom() != null) {
            player.currentRoom = player.currentRoom.getWestRoom();
            System.out.println("You are in " + player.currentRoom.getName() + ". " + player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription());
        } else {
            System.out.println("You cannot go that way");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The short answer to your question of how to get the two classes working together: you *don't*.  Longer answer: One program is a linear console app and the other is an event-driven GUI and the two programming paradigms don't mesh well or easily together. Your best bet is to re-write the code that holds the program logic (non user-interface state and behavior information code) in such a way that it can be used in any type of UI paradigm, linear console or event-driven GUI, and then mesh your GUI with this new code.

Comment: Also, please take a look at my related answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246328/).

Comment: I see. I'm not sure how to achieve that, but I will try and figure it out. Thank you very much for your answer. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some good things in your code as well as several major issues that may hamper your ability to mash a GUI with your current console-program code, and these include:

- You do have some separation of the your program logic into separate classes such as Player, Map, and Room classes, and that is a very good thing, but you still could do more separation of the logic, and doing so can simplify your code making it easier to debug and enhance.
- The Player class contains a Player instance, I'm not sure why. The outer main class should probably be re-named from `Player` to the `Game` class, and the Player class should be a totally separate class, one that holds the state of a *single* player instance, and shouldn't create instances of itself as you're doing. The key is to strive to "oop-ify" your code, especially the "model" portion of the code, the code that holds the non-user interface program logic, to make it more object-oriented, since this will make it much easier to allow you to connect a GUI or any other interface, to your model.
- Your model (again, named Player) has user interface (UI) code within it: it has Scanner input code within it and println statements. This is problematic, especially now since you want to enhance the program and make it work with a GUI. The key thing that you must do, first and foremost, is to separate the user interface code (agian the code that gets input from the user and that displays output to the user) outside of model class, which is, again, class that holds the program logic.
- Your Player class has a lot of non-Player code cluttering it. A basic OOPs principle is that a class should have a single responsibility (called the "single responsibility rule"), and so your Player class should only have code that is needed to encapsulate Player state (such as name, Room, perhaps other properties such as strength, weapons, health, intelligence....) and Player behavior (methods that allow Player to interact with other classes), and nothihg more or less.
- Going on the same vein, it appears that all the program data and behaviors seem to be hard-wired into this single main Player class that drives the program. This is very limiting and will hinder your ability to create a rich playing environment with many rooms, items in the rooms, and things like this. Divide and conquer -- get that information out of the main program and put it into OOP-compliant classes, including a Room class that has fields for items it might contain, that has knowledge of its own connections to other rooms.
- Your GUI program extends the Player object. This is a major problem since this program structure does not pass the basic test of inheritance, the "is-a" test: logically is a GUI a more specific type of player (much like a Dog is a more specific type of Animal, a structure which passes the "is-a" test)? No, it is not, and while this distinction may seem pendantic, you may try to use Player fields within the GUI class because of this inheritance, but if you try to do this, the code will not work correctly. Remove this inheritance, and instead try to connect classes through "composition" where one class holds an instance of another, rather than extends another. So for instance, the GUI could possibly hold a Player variable rather than extend from Player.

---

## Bottom line:
You will want to fully "OOP-ify" your code *before* trying to add a GUI

In order for the program to be able to well-meshed with a GUI, I would suggest making your underlying logical code (the non-user interface logic code) much more object-oriented with classes that all have a *single responsibility*, classes that are easily *testable* in isolation (away from GUI or any user interface). Start with first principles and the program will be *much* easier to build.

So, for example, classes that could be considered for an adventure game include:

- A Direction class, or better a Direction *enum*.

This would encapsulate the idea of "direction" and would be used for objects in the game to know which direction they are going and to be able to communicate this to other objects using constants, rather than Strings. The user of an enum would allow the compiler to check that directions are being used correctly, since if you used Strings, say, "West", the compiler would not automatically know if you mis-typed the String and used "Best" instead.

Something simple like this, for example:

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
}
```

- A GameRoom class

This would hold information telling it its location in the grid of rooms, Strings for both name and description properties, and a game player field or a `List` of game players if more than one are allowed, perhaps something that contains code like this:....

```
public class GameRoom {
    // map with connections to other game rooms
    private Map<Direction, GameRoom> connections = new HashMap<Direction, GameRoom>();
    
    // location information
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    // identifying information
    private String roomName;
    private String description;
    
    // holds any player objects that may be in the room
    private List<GamePlayer> playersInRoom = new ArrayList<>();
```

The class will have appropriate constructors as well as getter and setter methods and also:

An `addPlayer(...)` method that allows the game to add a player into the room:

```
public void addPlayer(GamePlayer gamePlayer) {
    playersInRoom.add(gamePlayer);
    gamePlayer.setCurrentRoom(this); // we'll get to this later
}
```

A `public boolean move(...)` method that moves a player contained by the room to a connecting room. It first checks that the room actually contains the player being moved, and then next checks if the room has a connection to another room in the requested direction. If either are false, then the method returns false to let the calling code that the attempted move failed. Otherwise, if the move is allowed, it returns true:

```
public boolean move(GamePlayer gamePlayer, Direction direction) {
    
    // if the room doesn't currently hold this player
    if (!playersInRoom.contains(gamePlayer)) {
        return false; // invalid move request
    }
    
    // if the room doesn't have a connecting room in the requested direction
    if (!connections.containsKey(direction)) {
        return false;  // invalid move request
    }
    
    // otherwise, we're good
    playersInRoom.remove(gamePlayer);
    connections.get(direction).addPlayer(gamePlayer);
    return true;
}
```

- A GamePlayer class

This class will hold several properties such as a String for name and a GameRoom field for the current room, constructors, getter and setter methods. It's declaration and fields could look something like:

```
public class GamePlayer {
    private String name;
    private GameRoom currentRoom;
    //.... other properties
```

It too should have a move method that calls the currentRoom GameRoom's move method and returns the same boolean, a result that tells the calling code if the move was valid and successful:

```
public boolean move(Direction direction) {
    return currentRoom.move(this, direction);
}
```

- A GameModel class:

This will hold the *state* of the current game, fields for players, a data structure to hold all the rooms. It can have its own move method.....

---

Only after creating your OOP-compliant classes should you move to the next step: the creation of your GUI or "view" class/classes.  This class could hold a GameModel instance, and would be responsible for 1) displaying the *state* of the game (a visual representation of the rooms and the items that they hold), and 2) getting input from the user, and passing that input to the game model for processing.

I like to use an M-V-C program structure, which stands for "Model-View-Controller" where the program logic and GUI are kept as separate as possible, and there may be a controller class or classes that help tie the model and view together.  Another principle that I try to follow is to keep the GUI as "dumb" as possible. By dumb, I mean that it should get input from the user, perhaps do the most basic of input verifications, and should display the state of the model, but that's it. Almost all the "brains" of the program should be held by the model itself and not the view.

---

## Proof-of-concept Example:

An incomplete but running "proof-of-concept" example of what I am describing above is shown below. You should copy the program whole, paste it into your IDE into a single file named `VideoGame.java`, and then should be able to run it. It uses some concepts that you may not yet be familiar with, including the use of Key Bindings to get user input from the GUI and the use of PropertyChangeListeners and PropertyChangeSupport objects to allow clean communication between objects (to notify listeners if the *state* of one of the model object has changed). This program *should* respond to pressing of the arrow keys:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class VideoGame {
    private static final int[][] ROOM_GRID_KEY = { 
            {  1,  0,  0,  2,  0,  0,  3,  4 }, 
            {  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11,  0 },
            {  0, 12,  0, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0 }, 
            {  0, 14,  0,  0,  0,  0, 15, 16 }, 
            { 17, 18,  0, 19,  0,  0, 20,  0 },
            { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28 } 
        };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GameModel gameModel = new GameModel(ROOM_GRID_KEY);
            GameView gameView = new GameView();
            
            new GameController(gameModel, gameView);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Video Game");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(gameView);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```
class GameController {
    private GameModel gameModel;
    private GameView gameView;

    public GameController(GameModel gameModel, GameView gameView) {
        this.gameModel = gameModel;
        this.gameView = gameView;
        
        ModelListener modelListener = new ModelListener();
        
        gameView.setModel(gameModel);
        gameModel.addPropertyChangeListener(modelListener);
    }
    
    private class ModelListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            gameView.modelChange(evt);
        }
    }

}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DisplayPanel extends JPanel {
    private JPanel[][] panelGrid;
    private int gridCellSize;
    private GameModel gameModel;
    private GameRoom[][] roomGrid;
    
    public DisplayPanel(int gridCellSize) {
        this.gridCellSize = gridCellSize;       
    }
    
    public void setModel(GameModel gameModel) {
        this.gameModel = gameModel;
        this.roomGrid = gameModel.getRoomGrid();
        
        int rows = roomGrid.length;
        int cols = roomGrid[0].length;
        
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        
        panelGrid = new JPanel[rows][cols];
        for (int r = 0; r < panelGrid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < panelGrid[r].length; c++) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
                panelGrid[r][c] = panel;
                panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(gridCellSize, gridCellSize));
                if (roomGrid[r][c] == null) {
                    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
                    if (roomGrid[r][c].getPlayersInRoom().size() > 0) {
                        GamePlayer gamePlayer = roomGrid[r][c].getPlayersInRoom().get(0);
                        String name = gamePlayer.getName();
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
                        panel.add(label);
                    }
                }
                add(panel);
                
            }
        }
        
        // key bindings code
        addBindings(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), Direction.SOUTH);
        addBindings(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), Direction.NORTH);
        addBindings(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), Direction.WEST);
        addBindings(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), Direction.EAST);
    }

    private void addBindings(KeyStroke keyStroke, Direction direction) {
        int condition = WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
        InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
        ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
        
        Action action = new AbstractAction() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                gameModel.move(direction);
            }
        };
        
        inputMap.put(keyStroke, keyStroke.toString());
        actionMap.put(keyStroke.toString(), action);
    }

    public void modelChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        for (int r = 0; r < panelGrid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < panelGrid[r].length; c++) {
                JPanel panel = panelGrid[r][c];
                if (roomGrid[r][c] != null) {
                    if (roomGrid[r][c].getPlayersInRoom().size() > 0) {
                        GamePlayer gamePlayer = roomGrid[r][c].getPlayersInRoom().get(0);
                        String name = gamePlayer.getName();
                        JLabel label = new JLabel(name);
                        panel.add(label);
                    } else {
                        panel.removeAll();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    
    public GameModel getGameModel() {
        return gameModel;
    }
}
```

```
class GameView extends JPanel {
    private static final int CELL_SIZE = 80;
    private DisplayPanel displayPanel = new DisplayPanel(CELL_SIZE);
    private GameModel gameModel;
    // private JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    
    public GameView() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        
        add(displayPanel);
        // add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void setModel(GameModel gameModel) {
        this.gameModel = gameModel;
        displayPanel.setModel(gameModel);
    }

    public void modelChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        displayPanel.modelChange(evt);
    }

    public GameModel getGameModel() {
        return gameModel;
    }

}
```

```
class GameModel {
    public static final String GAME_MODEL = "game model";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private GameRoom[][] roomGrid;
    private GamePlayer player = new GamePlayer("Fred");

    public GameModel(int[][] roomGridKey) {
        roomGrid = new GameRoom[roomGridKey.length][roomGridKey[0].length];
        // fill room grid with rooms if 1 in grid key array, with null if 0
        for (int y = 0; y < roomGridKey.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < roomGridKey[0].length; x++) {
                roomGrid[y][x] = roomGridKey[y][x] != 0 ? new GameRoom("Some Room", "Some Description", x, y) : null;
            }
        }

        // make room connections:
        for (int y = 0; y < roomGrid.length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < roomGrid[0].length; x++) {
                GameRoom thisRoom = roomGrid[y][x];

                // if no room present, don't
                if (thisRoom == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (x > 0) {
                    GameRoom otherGameRoom = roomGrid[y][x - 1];
                    if (otherGameRoom != null) {
                        thisRoom.putConnection(Direction.WEST, otherGameRoom);
                    }
                }
                if (x < roomGrid[0].length - 1) {
                    GameRoom otherGameRoom = roomGrid[y][x + 1];
                    if (otherGameRoom != null) {
                        thisRoom.putConnection(Direction.EAST, otherGameRoom);
                    }
                }

                if (y > 0) {
                    GameRoom otherGameRoom = roomGrid[y - 1][x];
                    if (otherGameRoom != null) {
                        thisRoom.putConnection(Direction.NORTH, otherGameRoom);
                    }
                }
                if (y < roomGrid.length - 1) {
                    GameRoom otherGameRoom = roomGrid[y + 1][x];
                    if (otherGameRoom != null) {
                        thisRoom.putConnection(Direction.SOUTH, otherGameRoom);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // put player in top left room
        GameRoom currentRoom = roomGrid[0][0];
        if (currentRoom == null) {
            // some big error occurred
            System.err.println("Current room at 0, 0 is null. Exiting");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        player.setCurrentRoom(currentRoom);
        currentRoom.addPlayer(player);
        player.addPropertyChangeListener(pce -> pcSupport.firePropertyChange(GAME_MODEL, null, player));

    }

    public boolean move(Direction direction) {
        boolean success = player.move(direction);
        return success;
    }

    public GamePlayer getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }

    public GameRoom[][] getRoomGrid() {
        return roomGrid;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(GAME_MODEL, listener);
    }

}
```

```
class GamePlayer {
    public static final String GAME_PLAYER = "game player";
    private SwingPropertyChangeSupport pcSupport = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);
    private String name;
    private GameRoom currentRoom;

    public GamePlayer(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean move(Direction direction) {
        boolean success = currentRoom.move(this, direction);
        return success;
    }

    public void setCurrentRoom(GameRoom currentRoom) {
        GameRoom oldValue = this.currentRoom;
        GameRoom newValue = currentRoom;
        this.currentRoom = currentRoom;
        pcSupport.firePropertyChange(GAME_PLAYER, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public GameRoom getCurrentRoom() {
        return currentRoom;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GamePlayer [name=" + name + ", currentRoom=" + currentRoom + "]";
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        pcSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(GAME_PLAYER, listener);
    }

}
```

```
class GameRoom {
    // map with connections to other game rooms
    private Map<Direction, GameRoom> connections = new HashMap<Direction, GameRoom>();
    
    // location information
    private int x;
    private int y;
    
    // identifying information
    private String roomName;
    private String description;
    
    // holds any player objects that may be in the room
    private List<GamePlayer> playersInRoom = new ArrayList<>();

    public GameRoom(String roomName, String description, int x, int y) {
        this.roomName = roomName;
        this.description = description;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean move(GamePlayer gamePlayer, Direction direction) {
        
        // if the room doesn't currently hold this player
        if (!playersInRoom.contains(gamePlayer)) {
            return false; // invalid move request
        }
        
        // if the room doesn't have a connecting room in the requested direction
        if (!connections.containsKey(direction)) {
            return false;  // invalid move request
        }
        
        // otherwise, we're good
        playersInRoom.remove(gamePlayer);
        connections.get(direction).addPlayer(gamePlayer);
        return true;
    }

    public void addPlayer(GamePlayer gamePlayer) {
        playersInRoom.add(gamePlayer);
        gamePlayer.setCurrentRoom(this);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    public String getRoomName() {
        return roomName;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public List<GamePlayer> getPlayersInRoom() {
        return playersInRoom;
    }

    public Map<Direction, GameRoom> getConnections() {
        return connections;
    }

    public void putConnection(Direction direction, GameRoom otherGameRoom) {
        connections.put(direction, otherGameRoom);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GameRoom [x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "]";
    }

}
```

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH, EAST, SOUTH, WEST
}
```

Again, compile and run this code and use the arrow keys to move "Fred" around the grid.

---

A more complete program would separate the data completely out of the code and allow for file I/O for reading in the room grid into the program, possibly by creating a CSV file or files to hold the room information, or if the data is expected to grow and be more complex, then a relational database such as one that uses one of the flavors of SQL.

Comment: Wow, this is gold. I never expected any answer to go above and beyond like this. If I had enough reputation I would upvote your answer. I'm sure to look through your answer in detail. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Since you've made the GUI extend the player, all you need to do is call the desired function from the ActionListener on the input field.

```
    commandLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String input = commandLine.getText();

            if (input == "go north") {
                GoNorth();                
            }
            // .....

        }
    });
```

However, things are pretty messy. There's no real reason for the GUI to extend the player, for starters. I'd advise you to separate the GUI class from Player. That way, you won't need to use the Scanner or Print, and instead collect all your GUI functionality in the GUI class.

For instance:

```
public void goNorth() {
    if (player.currentRoom.getNorthRoom() != null) {
        player.currentRoom = player.currentRoom.getNorthRoom();
        
        gui.print("You are in " + player.currentRoom.getName() + ". " + player.currentRoom.getRoomDescription())
    } else {
        gui.print("You cannot go that way");
    }
}
```

You would need to implement a print function in the GUI class, that added a line of text to the message box, but I'm sure you were planning on that to begin with.

In the GUI class, you would then have a reference to the player, so reading the input field would look something like this:

```
commandLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String input = commandLine.getText();
        switch(input) {
            case "go north":
                player.goNorth();
                break;
            ...
        }


    }
});
```

Comment: `if (input == "go north") {`?!?

Comment: I just used whatever syntax they used in the Player class in order to keep it simple. There are obviously better ways of implementing a command line.

Comment: Your answer is wrong, in several ways. First and foremost, the structure of the UI's cannot mesh as you're suggesting that it can and you may wish to consider showing a working [mre] example in your answer. For another, basic Java tells you to never compare Strings using `==`.  Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: The original poster never used `==` to compare Strings in their own code, so why you are suggesting a Java newbie do this is beyond logic.

Comment: You're right, I've edited it to use a switch statement like the original code.

Comment: But I'm not sure what you about the UI's not being able to mesh. I'm telling OP to put all the UI code into the GUI class and only handle the player logic in the player class. All they need is a reference to Player from GUI and a reference to GUI from Player.

Comment: Also this: *"Since you've made the GUI extend the player..."* -- is a blunder on the original poster's part and a correct answer would tell them not to do this. This does not pass the most basic "is-a" test of inheritance, and in doing this will lead to non-functioning code. Also, how would a game structured in this way allow for multiple Player objects? Again, it makes no sense and should be stricken from the OP's logic.

Comment: You're obviously just being pedantic for the sake of it. I do advise OP to separate GUI from the player class, but only after I've corrected their mistake. Having one player is perfectly fine if you're making a text-based game. If they want to expand on it, it's up to them, but their question wasn't about what the best practices for making a video game are.

Comment: I strongly disagree. If you don't see that having the GUI extend the Player is a major design flaw, then you really shouldn't be answering this question since this *is* a major design flaw, one that will hamper the program from functioning.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're trolling right now. 70% of my answer is telling him how to separate the GUI from the player.  You either didn't read the entire comment, or your reading comprehension is terrible. Either way, you should think twice before starting discussions in the comment thread.

Comment: No, I'm not trolling, and in fact, I'm dead serious. Object-oriented issues are the first issues that must be fixed prior to trying to shoe-horn a GUI onto a program. It may seem over-kill to the OP, but if they wants to have anything that runs well, that is testable and configurable, they need to start from first principles. That is why this question is so very difficult to answer, because currently the OP has the cart before the horse: they are trying to add a GUI to an incomplete program.

Comment: Since I have added my own answer, I have decided to remove my down-vote on your answer, since that isn't quite fair in my book since it artificially raises the relative ranking of my own answer. In fact, if you improve your answer, I am more than willing to up-vote it, if I like it since the whole goal of this site is the creation and sharing and rewarding of *good* information.

Comment: I agree with your point about object-oriented design being a crucial part of creating functioning programs, but it's obvious that OP isn't at a level where that's relevant yet. They barely seem to understand how classes work. I think your answer is good as a 'further reading' answer, but I can see how a beginner who just learned what a class is could get overwhelmed if you dump an entire program on them when they just asked for a tip on how to get the classes to work together.